# Why do we need to type cast an enum in C#

Tags: c#

I have an enum like:

```
public enum Test:int
{
   A=1, 
   B=2
}
```

So here I know my enum is an int type but if I want to do something like following:

```
int a = Test.A;
```

this doesn't work.

If I have a class like:

```
public class MyTest
{
    public static int A =1;
}
```

I can say ,

```
int a = MyTest.A;
```

Here I don't need to cast `A` to int explicitly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97391/how-to-get-the-underlying-value-of-an-enum

Comment: It's a design choice. I guess the C# inventors think it's safer and/or more readable.

Comment: What compelling reason would exist for this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your updated example:

```
public class MyTest
{
    public static int A =1;
}
```

And usage:

```
int a = MyTest.A;
```

That's *not* how enums look. Enums look more like (comments are places where we differ from a real enum):

```
public struct MyTest /* Of course, this isn't correct, because we'll inherit from System.ValueType. An enum should inherit from System.Enum */
{
    private int _value; /* Should be marked to be treated specially */
    private MyTest(int value) /* Doesn't need to exist, since there's some CLR fiddling */
    {
       _value = value;
    }

    public static explicit operator int(MyTest value) /* CLR provides conversions automatically */
    {
       return value._value;
    }
    public static explicit operator MyTest(int value) /* CLR provides conversions automatically */
    {
       return new MyTest(value);
    }

    public static readonly MyTest A = new MyTest(1); /* Should be const, not readonly, but we can't do a const of a custom type in C#. Also, is magically implicitly converted without calling a constructor */

    public static readonly MyTest B = new MyTest(2); /* Ditto */
}
```

Yes, you can *easily* get to the "underlying" int value, but the values of `A` and `B` are still strongly typed as being of type `MyTest`. This makes sure you don't *accidentally* use them in places where they're not appropriate.

Comment: That's very good example , thanks , now I understand why I have to do casting. Means I have to do unboxing every time I use the value.

Comment: That's *not* how enums look - because you can cast *any* `int` value to an enum with an underlying value of that type. Enums are "unsafe" in that respect, unfortunately. Also, they're value types rather than reference types.

Comment: @Praveen: No, it doesn't mean you have to do unboxing. Converting from an enum value to its numeric value involves no boxing or unboxing at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I didn't say it was 100% - I said they look "more like". I was trying to convey to the OP that whilst there may be static fields containing the named values, the types of those static fields is the type of the enum. I was trying to help them see where their example didn't work. I could add some operators to support conversions in both directions, but it seemed unnecessary.

Comment: The problem is that there are *very significant* differences between the class you've given and what enums really look like. It looks *hardly anything* like what you've provided, I'd say. What you've provided looks more like what Java does.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I've converted to a value type and added the needed conversions. Of course, there's still a lot missing, and it's still not what an enum really looks like, because we're still trying to write something that will compile in C#.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Right, that's much more like it.

Answer (score 18):

> So here I know my enum is an int type

No, it's not. It has an *underlying* type of `int`, but it's a separate type. Heck, that's half the point of having enums in the first place - that you can keep the types separate.

When you want to convert between an enum value and its numeric equivalent, you cast - it's not that painful, and it keeps your code cleaner in terms of type safety. Basically it's one of those things where the rarity of it being the *right* thing to do makes it appropriate to make it explicit.

EDIT: One oddity that you should be aware of is that there *is* an implicit conversion from the constant value 0 to the enum type:

```
Test foo = 0;
```

In fact, in the MS implementation, it can be *any* kind of constant 0:

```
Test surprise = 0.0;
```

That's a bug, but one which it's too late to fix :)

I believe the rest for this implicit conversion was to make it simpler to check whether any bits are set in a flags enum, and other comparisons which would use "the 0 value". Personally I'm not a fan of that decision, but it's worth at least being aware of it.

Comment: I mean I know the enum is int, isn't it so confusing that I can tell that my enum has underlying type int but i can't use it like an int.

Comment: @Praveen: No, the enum isn't int. The enum has a *storage representation* of int, but it's a separate type. You *shouldn't* use it like an int without explicitly doing so...

Comment: @Praveen: *"I know the enum is int"* - You intuitively understand that it's representing an `int`, yes.  But as far as the compiler is concerned, it's a different type.  Just like if you create a class which has no other member than a single public `int`.  You "know it's just an `int`", but it's really an entirely different type which just happens to internally represent its only data member as an `int`.

Comment: @David: when I have a class with only a public int i'll not have to do  type cast it coz i know it's an int, confusion is why I have to do type cast ?

Comment: @Praveen: I still don't get your confusion here. They're different types. You need to explicitly cast from one to the other to tell the compiler "Yes, I know that it's really the enum type, but I want its underlying numeric value." That requirement keeps your code cleaner because it means you're telling anyone *reading* your code that you know you're doing that too.

Comment: @JonSkeet: The question is not about the type I mean enum Test, but it's member like A,B in my example, why do I need to type cast them to int while they are already int ?

Comment: @Praveen: The question very much _is_ about the type.  You need to cast it because it's _not_ an int.  It uses the same data structure as an int to store its underlying data, but at a _type_ level (which is what casting is all about), it's not an int.  The compiled result will be treated very much like an int, but the C# type is different.

Comment: I can see the reason of casting an int to an Enum:int but why should we need to cast that enum to an int? I believe it would be better for the eyes if only it's possible to convert an Enum:int to an integer implicitly. Just like conversions between a child class and its base (or between Nullable<T> and T); an integer can or can not be converted to an Enum:int based on it's value but an Enum:int can be converted to an int in any case. Even the syntax of creating an Enum looks like deriving from the specified type, why wouldn't the conversations between an enum and its storage type be likewise?

Comment: @d4wn: There's no implicit conversion from `Nullable<T>` to `T` - only vice versa. Regardless of the syntax, the enums *aren't* "derived from" their underlying types, and shouldn't be treated as such. Conversion from an enum type to the numeric type should be relatively rare and very deliberate - so I'd want to see it in the code, for clarity.

Comment: I meant exactly that when I mentioned Nullable<T>. So the reason why there is no implicit conversion _from_ Enum _to_ its storage type is that it looks more clear and indicative. Is this correct?

Comment: @d4wn: I would surmise so, yes. Not that I'm privy to the design notes of the C# language committee...

Answer (score 5):

["The underlying type specifies how much storage is allocated for each enumerator. However, an explicit cast is needed to convert from enum type to an integral type".](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The enum values are not of `int` type. `int` is the base type of the enum. The enums are technically ints but logically (from the perspective of the C# language) not. `int` (`System.Int32`) is the base type of all enums by default, if you don't explicitly specify another one.

Answer (score 2):

You enum is of type `Test`.  It is not `int` just because your enum has integers values.

You can cast your enum to get the int value:

```
int a = (int) Test.A;
```

Comment: That I know I can cast it but the question is why do i need to cast it ?

Comment: My guess is that it is a design decision to have us explicitly cast.